# Horizontal grid lines in plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

The standard R plotly scatter/line graph comes with both vertical and horizontal grid lines. I cannot find the command to select only vertical or horizontal lines. I want the latter. So far I have found the following commands in the [offiial guide](https://plot.ly/r/axes/):

```
showgrid = FALSE/TRUE
gridcolor = ...
gridwidth = ...
```

Any idea which is the command to select subset of grid lines?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit:** The `showline` argument is indeed for the axes. `showgrid` should work for the gridlines, called within each axis agrument in `layout()`.

```
plot_ly(x = c(1,2), y = c(1,2)) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(gridcolor = "black"))
```

[image]