# How to remove gridlines and have clear background for plotly in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

I am trying to create a 3D plot using RStudio.
So far, what I have produced is something similar to this (code from https://plotly.com/r/3d-scatter-plots/)

```
library(plotly)
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                     zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')))

fig
```

However, I also want to edit the theme/background. Just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT8MP.png), I want clear background without any gridlines. I understand this image is probably generated by `scatter3D`, so I am wondering if plot_ly does anything similar? Like themes, bgcolor, etc? How do I remove the gridlines?

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to what was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720305/horizontal-grid-lines-in-plotly-r), specifying `showgrid = F` in `layout()` for the x, y and z axes will remove all the gridlines:

```
library(plotly)
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight', showgrid = F),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower', showgrid = F),
                                   zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time', showgrid = F)))

fig
```

It is also possible to add lines for the x, y and z axes to the plot after removing the gridlines by additionally specifying `showline = T` in `layout()` for each the x, y and z axes:

```
library(plotly)
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight', showgrid = F, showline = T),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower', showgrid = F, showline = T),
                                   zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time', showgrid = F, showline = T)))

fig
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Any idea on how to adjust thickness of grid